# What does this variable mean?

Tags: c#

i saw this in the internet, and i couldn't think what is this about:

they created the boolean which is named obstacles and set it to false.

```
   public bool obstacles = false;
```

But, what is this line about:

```
    obstacles = obstacles ? false : true;

    if (obstacles)
    {
        transform.renderer.material.color = new Color(.5f, .5f, 0.0f);
    }

    else
    {
        transform.renderer.material.color = Color.white;
    }
```

I know the if and else function, when there is an obstacles, turn the material to the assigned color, or if there is not an obstacles, turn the material into white color. But, what is this line about: obstacles = obstacles ? false : true;

Thanks.. Sorry for this newbie question.

Comment: I would rather write `obstacles = !obstacles` or go with Steve's approach, but now you know what it meaans.

Comment: @Silvermind, probably yours is better

Comment: @Silvermind: so if i want to take your advice. The code will be like `if` statement will execute the `obstacles` or `obstacles = true`, `else` statement will execute the `!obstacles` or `obstacles = false`. Do i am wrong in some line sir? Yes, now i know it already. Thanks to you and everyone

Comment: Yes you're right, but if you can I would rename `obstacles` in `hasObstacles`, that way it is more readable when you write `if(hasObstacles) trueCondition else falseCondition`

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it clearly now

Answer (score 5):

`?:` This is called the [ternary  operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on
>   the value of a Boolean expression. Following is the syntax for the
>   conditional operator.
>
> **condition ? first_expression : second_expression;**
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The condition must evaluate to true or false. If condition is true,
>   first_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. If condition is
>   false, second_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. Only one
>   of the two expressions is evaluated.
>
> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

The example from MSDN makes it clear:

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string classify;

// if-else construction.
if (input < 0)
    classify = "negative";
else
    classify = "positive";

// ?: conditional operator.
classify = (input < 0) ? "negative" : "positive";
```

As Steeve correctly pointed out, you may try like this using a if else statement to what you want to accomplish:

```
if (!obstacles)
{
    transform.renderer.material.color = new Color(.5f, .5f, 0.0f);
    obstacles = true;
}

else
{
    transform.renderer.material.color = Color.white;
    obstacles = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

All the answers explain what is a ternary operator and they are all right, but everyone fails to note the elephant in the room. Why not to remove the ternary operator and write the code above as

```
if (!obstacles)
{
    // Enter the if with obstacles = false, but execute the code for true then flip obstacles
    transform.renderer.material.color = new Color(.5f, .5f, 0.0f);
    obstacles = true;
}

else
{
    // Enter the else with obstacles = true, but execute the code for false then flip obstacles
    transform.renderer.material.color = Color.white;
    obstacles = false;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `obstacles = !obstacles`?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead because I have not thought of it :-) See the comments of Silvermind above.

Answer (score 2):

This line basically "flips" the value of "obstacles" variable to the opposite value. If obstacles is true, it changes it's value to false and vice-versa. So, the author of this code probably is trying to draw something similar to an interleaved pattern here.

Answer (score 1):

This is the ternary operator. Basically, if condition is true, execute first statement, else execute the second.

condition ? first_expression : second_expression;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
?: called ternary operator
```

functionality :

```
var value= (Condition/Expression)? value1 :value2;
```

means

```
if(Condition== true)
value=value1;
else
value=value2;
```

Your code:

```
public static bool obstacles = true;
bool value=(obstacles = obstacles) ? false : true;
```

output: `value=false`

your `expression => (obstacles = obstacles)` always evaluates to whatever value is there in `obstacles` so here it is `true`.
hence first value here `false` will be assigned to your `variable` `value`.